# Keep rounding upto specified digit if non zero

Tags: c#, .net, math

I want to round Up decimal values upto two points. But for any number which is less than 0.01, I want to return 0.01.

```
RoundUp(0.146,2) should return 0.15

RoundUp(0.0003,2) should return 0.01
```

In C#, I am currently using `Math.Round`, with `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` parameter, but for

```
Math.Round(0.0003, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

it returns `0`.

Is there any in built method in Math namespace, which I can use to get desired behavior?

Currently I am using this method

```
    private double GetRoundUpValue(double price, int roundUpto)
    {
        Debug.Assert(roundUpto == 2 || roundUpto == 3);
        var val = Math.Round(price, roundUpto, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        Double minValue = roundUpto == 2 ? 0.01 : 0.001;
        return val < minValue ? minValue : val;
    }
```

Comment: Should 0.143 be 0.14 or 0.15? Are you always going up or only in the 0 < x < 0.01 case?

Comment: 0.143 should return 0.015.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But for any number which is less than 0.01, I want to return 0.01.

Then why not keep it simple and just use something like this:

```
Math.Max(Math.Round(0.0003, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), 0.01);
```

Or if you need something more general, to round to *n* decimal places, use something like this:

```
private double GetRoundUpValue(double price, int places)
{
    var minValue = Math.Pow(0.1, places);
    return Math.Max(Math.Round(price, places, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), minValue);
}
```

Also note, that 'rounding away from zero' is not the same as 'rounding up' (for that, you can look at [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Ceiling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). So I'd recommend either changing the name of this method or it's body to be more clear about what's actually going on inside of it.

For example:

```
private double GetRoundUpValue(double price, int places)
{
    var scale = Math.Pow(10, places);
    return Math.Ceiling(price * scale) / scale;
}
```

Comment: I like it! KISS is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, you are right about diff between rounding up and rounding away from zero. Changing the method body :).